# Nth child in table not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `td:nth-child('n')` is not working over in my table it gives null in the log Where as it is working when i use `children[n]` it is a simple function for searching

I couldn't find the reason why it is giving out a null.. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Table Searching</title>
<style>
    th{
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
    table, th, td{
        font-size: 20px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="search">
<button class="s" onclick="Search()">Search by Name</button>
<button class="s" onclick="Search()">Search by Country</button>
<button class="s" onclick="Search()">Search by Pet</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Pet</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Abhi</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>koala</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Riya</td>
        <td>France</td>
        <td>Parrot</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sid</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>Pig</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kritika</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Cat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Kartik</td>
        <td>China</td>
        <td>Frog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Radhika</td>
        <td>India</td>
        <td>Dog</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    var input=document.getElementsByName("search")[0];
    var s=document.getElementsByClassName("s");
    var n=0;

    function Search(){
    for (var j=0; j<s.length; j++) 
    {
        console.log("element");
        console.log(s[j]);
        console.log("target");
        console.log(event.target);
        if(s[j]==event.target){
            n=j;
            console.log(n);
        }
    }
        var val= input.value;
        var a=document.querySelectorAll("table > tbody > tr");
        console.log(a);
        for(var i =0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            var d = a[i].querySelector('td:nth-child("+n+")');
            console.log(d);
            if(d.innerHTML.toLowerCase()==val.toLowerCase()){
                a[i].style.display="";
            }
            else
            {
                a[i].style.display="none";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use correct quotes `'td:nth-child('+n+')')`

Comment: Using the table object and the table cols Collection is a faster solution.

Comment: I had already tried `'td:nth-child('+n+')`  didn't work so changed the code
thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the three reasons why you are giving out `null` in your code:

1. First, as stated by Satpal, this code `'td:nth-child("+n+")'` **will not replace `n` by its value**. It's like writing `td:nth-child("+n+")` in css. 
   The solution for this is to write: `'td:nth-child(' + n + ')'`. You then concatenate the value of `n` with the rest of the string
2. The value of `n` is an index in a array, so it starts at `0` and ends at `array.length - 1`. The problem is that the `nth-child` selector actually selects the nth-child (brilliant naming), so if `n` is `0` (in the case of searching by name), you'll try to select the 0th-child, wihich doesn't exist... You then have to write: 'td:nth-child(' + (n + 1) + ')' or change the definition of `n`
3. You have no `<tbody>` tag in your HTML. Which means that all the content of the table will be wrapped in a `tbody` and your selector `document.querySelectorAll("table > tbody > tr")`will also selects the header of your table. To avoid that, change your HTML accordingly.

Something like that:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Pet</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Abhi</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
            <td>koala</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Riya</td>
            <td>France</td>
            <td>Parrot</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sid</td>
            <td>UK</td>
            <td>Pig</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kritika</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
            <td>Cat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kartik</td>
            <td>China</td>
            <td>Frog</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Radhika</td>
            <td>India</td>
            <td>Dog</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a jsfiddle where the search works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n23685b6/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the solution it did work but isn't there any other way i could get the indexing right without changing the definition of `n` 
somewhat like a `.eq()` in Jquery @RichardCasetta

Comment: Hello Tannmay,

Here is what you can do:

  
Replace `a[i].querySelector('td:nth-child(' + n + ')')` by `a[i].querySelectorAll('td')[n]`. You'll then select all the `td` as an array (which is good because `n` is an index in an array, so you just have to select the element at the nth place then. Here is the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n23685b6/2/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollToNthChild = (): *  => {
var tableBody = document.getElementById('event-table-body');
var tableRows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
let targetElement = tableRows[7];
targetElement.scrollIntoView();
```

}